# Performance of querying relational data with document-based nosql (mongodb, couchdb, and riak, etc)

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, rdbms, riak, nosql

To follow up on my question on [modeling relational data with nosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591943/nosql-referential-data), I have read several articles on the subject:

[Nosql doesn't mean non-relational](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/03/08/nosql-doesnt-mean-non-relational/)

[Nosql Ecommerce Example](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/06/nosql-railsconf-2010-ecommerce-example.html)

They seem to suggest that nosql can handle normalized, relational data.

So let's continue with the example I had before, a CMS system that have two types of data: article and authors, where article has an reference (by ID) to author.

Below are the operations the system needs to support:

1. Fetch a article by id along with the author
2. Fetch all articles by particular author
3. Find the first 10 article(s) with the author(s) sorted by creation date

I would like to understand the performance of these operation when compare to the same operation if the same data were stored on RDBMS.  **In particular, please specify if the operation uses MapReduce, require multple trips to the nosql store (Links), or [pre-join](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking)**

I would like to limit to discussion to **document-based** nosql solution like mongodb, couchdb, and riak.

**Edit 1:**

[Spring-data project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) is avalible on Riak and Mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MongoDB, you wouldn't use embedded documents for the author record. So the pre-join is out, it's multiple trips to the DB. However, you can cache the author and only need to make that second trip once for each record. The queries you indicated are pretty trivial in MongoDB.

```
var article = db.articles.find({id: article_id}).limit(1);
var author = db.authors.find({id: article.author_id});
```

If you are using an ORM/ODM to manage your entities within your application, this would transparent. It would be two trips to the db though. They should be fast responses though, two hits shouldn't be noticeable at all.

Finding articles by a given author is just reverse...

```
var author = db.authors.find({id: author_name}).limit(1);
var articles = db.articles.find({author_id: author.id});
```

So again, two queries but the single author fetch should be fast and can easily be cached.

```
var articles = db.articles.find({}).sort({created_at: 1}).limit(10);
var author_ids = articles.map(function(a) { return a.author_id });
var authors = db.authors.find({id: { '$in': authors_ids }});
```

Lastly, again, two queries but just a tiny bit more complex. You can run these in a mongo shell to see what the results might be like.

I'm not sure this is worth writing a map reduce to complete. A couple quick round trips might have a little more latency but the mongo protocol is pretty fast. I wouldn't be overly worried about it.

Lastly, real performance implications of doing it this way... Since ideally you'd only be querying on indexed fields in the document, it should be pretty quick. The only additional step is a second round trip to get the other documents, depending how your application and db is structures, this is likely not a big deal at all. You can tell mongo to only profile queries that take over a given threshold (100 or 200ms by default when turned on), so you can keep an eye on what's taking time for your program as data grows.

The one befit you have here that an RDMS does not offer is much easier breaking apart of data. What happens when you expand your application beyond CMS to support other things but uses the same authentication store? It just happens to be a completely separate DB now, that's shared across many applications. It's much simpler to perform these queries across dbs - with RDMS stores it's a complex process.

I hope this helps you in your NoSQL discovery!

Comment: You and Gates both gave very detailed answer that addressed my question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to toss in a CouchDB answer for anyone who might be curious. :)

As mentioned in the first answer above, embedding the author document into the article document is unwise, so the examples below assume two document types: articles and authors.

CouchDB uses MapReduce queries typically written in JavaScript (but Python, Ruby, Erlang and others are availble). The results of a MapReduce query are stored in an index upon their first request and that stored index is used to for all future look-ups. Changes to the database are added to the index upon further requests.

CouchDB's API is completely HTTP-based, so all requests to the database are HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) at various URLs. I'll be listing both the MapReduce queries (written in JavaScript) along with the URL used to request related results from the index.

**1. Fetch a article by id along with the author**

The simplest method for doing this is two direct document lookups:

```
GET /db/{article_id}
GET /db/{author_id}
```

...where {author_id} is the value obtained from the article's author_id field.

**2. Fetch all articles by particular author**

MapReduce

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'article') {
    emit(doc.author_id, doc);
  }
}
```

```
GET /db/_design/cms/_view/articles_by_author?key="{author_id}"
```

...where {author_id} is the actual ID of the author.

**3. Find the first 10 article(s) with the author(s) sorted by creation date**

MapReduce

```
function (doc) {
  function arrayDateFromTimeStamp(ts) {
    var d = new Date(ts);
    return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()];
  }

  var newdoc = doc;
  newdoc._id = doc.author_id;
  newdoc.created_at = arrayDateFromTimeStamp(doc.created_at);

  if (doc.type === 'article') {
    emit(newdoc.created_at, newdoc); 
  }
}
```

It's possible to do include style "joins" in CouchDB using `?include_docs=true` in a view request. If you include a "_id" key in the value side of the emit (the second argument), then adding `include_docs=true` to your query parameters will include the doc referenced by the specified "_id" In the case above, we're replacing the document's own "_id" (which we don't need anymore) with the referenced author's "_id" (the value of "author_id" in the article document). Requesting the top 10 articles with their related author info looks like this:

```
GET /db/_design/cms/_view/articles_by_date?descending=true&limit=10&include_docs=true
```

Requesting that URL will return a list of the most recent 10 articles in a format similar to:

```
{"rows":[
  { "id":"article_id",
    "key":[2011, 9, 3, 12, 5, 41],
    "value":{"_id":"author_id", "title":"..."},
    "doc":{"_id":"author_id", "name":"Author Name"}
  }
]}
```

Using this same index you can get a list of all the documents any any year, month, day, hour, etc granularity with or without author data.

There are also methods for using view collation to aggregate several documents together out of a single document (like a page in a CMS referencing disparate content). There's some info on how to do that in these slides I did for CouchConf in July: http://www.slideshare.net/Couchbase/couchconfsfdesigningcouchbasedocuments

If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Would this not fail in a distributed configuration (e.g. bigcouch, cloudant, CouchDB 2.0 when we get it)?

Comment: @MrGrieves the above scenario works on Cloudant and Apache CouchDB 2.0. Give it a try! :)

Comment: That's pretty cool.  I guess it means that the include document lookup happens at the end, after documents from all shards have been combined.  I this case, I assume that the performance is similar to making 2 round trips with all of the ids found in the first query sent in the body of the second query.

Answer (score 4):

> Fetch a article by id along with the author

**SQL**:

- 1 query
- 2 index lookups
- 2 data lookups
- data returned = article + author

**MongoDB**:

- 2 queries
- 2 index lookups
- 2 data lookups
- data returned = article + author

> Fetch all articles by particular author

**SQL**:

- 1 query
- 1 index lookup
- N data lookups
- data returned = N articles

**MongoDB**:

- 1 query
- 1 index lookup
- N data lookups
- data returned = N articles

> Find the first 10 article(s) with the author(s) sorted by creation date

**SQL**:

- 1 query
- 2 index lookups
- 11 to 20 data lookups (articles then unique authors)
- data returned = 10 articles + 10 authors

**MongoDB**:

- 2 queries (`articles.find().sort().limit(10)`, `authors.find({$in:[article_authors]})`
- 2 index lookups
- 11 to 20 data lookups (articles then unique authors)
- data returned = 10 articles + 1 to 10 authors

---

**Summary**

In two cases MongoDB requires an extra query, but does most of the same total work underneath. In some cases MongoDB returns less data over the network (no repeated entries). The join queries tend to be limited by the requirement that all the data to join live on the same box. If Authors and Articles live in different places, then you end up doing two queries anyways.

MongoDB tends to get better "raw" performance because it doesn't flush to disk with every write (so it's actually a "durability" tradeoff). It also has a much smaller query parser, so there's less activity per query.

From a basic performance standpoint these things are very similar. They just make different assumptions about your data and the trade-offs you want to make.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer!  Wish I could have pick both reply as the answer.

Comment: Your answer is detail and good. It raises a question in my mind, for query number 3, using that $in, if among 10 authors IDs, 3 are duplicates, that query will only return 7 authors right?  what if we, in the first place, want all the 10 authors to be returned even in case of duplication? Of course multiple hits to the db will solve the problem, but I am wondering over a more elegant solution. Thank you for the opinion