# Meteor and MongoDB dropdown population and integrity

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hopefully I can describe this correctly but I come from the RDBMS world and I'm building an inventory type application with Meteor.  Meteor and Mongodb may not be the best option for this application but hopefully it can be done and this seems like a circumstance that many converts will run into.

I'm trying to forget many of the things I know about relational databases and referential integrity so I can get my head wrapped around Mongodb but I'm hung up on this issue and how I would appropriately find the data with Meteor.

The inventory application will have a number of drop downs but I'll use an example to better explain.  Let's say I wanted to track an item so I'll want the Name, Qty on Hand, Manufacturer, and Location.  Much more than that but I'm keeping it simple.

The Name and Qty on Hand are easy since they are entered by the user but the Manufacturer and the Location should be chosen in a drop down from a data driven list (I'm assuming a Collection of sorts (or a new one added to the list if it is a new Manufacturer or Location).  Odds are that I will use the Autocomplete package as well but the point is the same.  I certainly wouldn't want the end user to misspell the Manufacturer name and thereby end up with documents that are supposed to have the same Manufacturer but that don't due to a typo.  So I need some way to enforce the integrity of the data stored for Manufacturer and Location.

The reason is because when the user is viewing all inventory items later, they will have the option of filtering the data.  They might want to filter the inventory items by Manufacturer.  Or by Location.  Or by both.

In my relational way of thinking this would just be three tables.  INVENTORY, MANUFACTURER, and LOCATION.  In the INVENTORY table I would store the ID of the related respective table row.

I'm trying to figure out how to store this data with Mongodb and, equally important, how to then find these Manufacturer and Location items to populate the drop down in the first place.

I found the following article which helps me understand some things but not quite what I need to connect the dots in my head.

Thanks!

[referential data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591943/nosql-referential-data)

**[EDIT]**

Still working at this, of course, but the best I've come up with is to do it normalized way much like is listed in the above article.  Something like this:

```
inventory
{
name: "Pen",
manufacturer: id: "25643"}, 
location: {id: "95789"} 
}

manufacturer
{
name: "BIC",
id: "25643"
}

location
{
name: "East Warehouse",
id: "95789"
}
```

Seems like this (in a more simple form) would have to be an extremely common need for many/most applications so want to make sure that I'm approaching it correctly.  Even if this example code were correct, should I use an id field with generated numbers like that or should I just use the built-in _id field?

Comment: Whether it is in Mongo or a SQL database, if you want your drop down populated with data, you build a drop down with id -> description. In Meteor you publish the collection of Manufacturers, and use that to fill the dropdown.
So far, nothing different.
When you'll want to SEARCH within your items, you'll have a different problem: if you only save IDs in an item, then you can't search by description. You need to look at DENORMALIZATION of your data: I would suggest you check: 
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: the trade-off comes from either doing the look up (JOIN) at search time, or denormalize the data but having to update each item if the manufacturer info changes. It all depends on how often it changes and how critical it is to keep these up to date. The key is to figure what are typical queries, and how most efficiently can the data be modeled to make those efficient (an not worry about storage space, that is cheap this days)

Answer (score 1):

I've come from a similar background so I don't know if I'm doing it correctly in my application but I have gone for a similar option to you. My app is an e-learning app so an Organisation will have many Courses.

So my schema looks similar to yours except I obviously have an array of objects that look like `{course_id: <id>}`

I then registered a helper than takes the data from the organisation and adds in the additional data I need about the courses.

```
// Gets Organisation Courses - In your case could get the locations/manufacturers
UI.registerHelper('organisationCourses', function() {
    user = Meteor.user();
    if (user) {
        organisation = Organisations.findOne({_id: user.profile.organisation._id});
        courses = organisation.courses.courses;
    return courses;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

// This takes the coursedata and for each course_id value finds and adds all the course data to the object
UI.registerHelper('courseData', function() {
    var courseContent = this;
    var course = Courses.findOne({'_id': courseContent.course_id});
    return _.extend(courseContent, _.omit(course, '_id'));
});
```

Then from my page all I have to call is:

```
{{#each organisationCourses}}
    {{#with courseData}}
        {{> admListCoursesItem}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

If I remember rightly I picked up this approach from an [EventedMind How-to video](https://www.eventedmind.com/classes/how-to/meteor-how-to-publish-a-many-to-many-relationship).